# How can I make a link to the result of a model method in my views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this method in my model:

```
  ## Finds invoice with next upcoming due date. ##
  def self.next_due
    where("due_date >= ? AND status = ?", Time.now, 'Open').order("due_date ASC").first ? where("due_date >= ?", Time.now).order("due_date ASC").first.due_date : ''
  end
```

This returns the due_date of the next invoice due.

I am trying to make a link_to to the actual invoice but so far have not been able to get it to work.

I feel like such an idiot because I can't make a simple link work when I've had no problems with links that I couldn't quickly sort out on my own up till now.

Is it possible to store the invoice returned by this query as a variable that I can call from the view and link to? If not, then how would I go about making the link?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
def self.next_due # This is a Class method!
  where("due_date >= ? AND status = ?", Time.now, 'Open').order("due_date ASC").first.try(:due_date)
end
```

And then in your views you can use it like this:

```
link_to Invoice.next_due, your_path_helper
```

---

Your naming is not really explicit, I would recommend you to change few things, like this:

```
# Invoice model
def self.next_invoice
  where("due_date >= ? AND status = ?", Time.now, 'Open').order("due_date ASC").first
end
```

And then call it in your views:

```
- if next_invoice = Invoice.next_invoice
  = link_to next_invoice.due_date, your_path_helper
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this later on, as I'm working on a different feature branch at the moment.

Comment: Okay. I'm still having trouble. Do I have to define a custom path helper for this?

Comment: no, you said "I am trying to make a link_to to the actual invoice", use the path you want for the second argument of the link_to (first argument = text displayed, second argument = path to go when clicking on the link, 3rd argument is an optional Hash of options). Depending on how you defined your routes, you can use the associated path helper.

Comment: Thanks! It's working now. If at some point in the future I wanted to make a link to the same invoice from the view of the associated parent, would I have to define a new query in a method in the parent model?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you return a the due date

```
class Invoice
  def self.next_due
    where("due_date >= ? AND status = ?", Time.now, 'Open').order("due_date ASC").first
  end
end
```

Then maybe in a helper

```
def next_due_invoice_link
  invoice = Invoice.next_due
  return if invoice.blank?
  link_to invoice.due_date, invoice_path(invoice)
end
```

Comment: Hi @j-dexx, thanks for responding. I tried that and ran into the same issue I've been getting, an undefined method error, this time it said 'due_date' is undefined.

Comment: Do you have a `due_date` field?

Comment: Yes, I do have a due_date field.

Comment: The error was coming from the part "link_to invoice.due_date, invoice_path(invoice)" I'm not sure why though.

Comment: The query works in rails console, and I can call the due_date attribute in the console, and if I remove the link_to and the path from the helper then invoice.due_date returns the due_date, no problem. I just can't make a link out of it.

Comment: Can you edit your question and post the actual code you're using in console and the actual code in your app?